# how to use protractor with selenium 3

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm trying to learn, do some tests with Protractor. I've been going through the information provided.
I'm stuck when I want to use Selenium 3 with protractor,

```
webdriver-manager update
```

I try above command to update, and still use selenium 2.53.1

any chances that i could use selenium 3 with protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did

`webdriver-manager --versions.standalone=3.0.1 update`

Then I had to provide the following option

`seleniumServerJar:'node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar'`

Answer (score 0):

You can update your selenium version by modifying the `config.json` used by webdriver-manager.

You can find the `config.json` file in `/node_modules/protractor/config.json` path.

Once you open the file you will see the content as below,

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
  "selenium": "2.52",
  "chromedriver": "2.21",
  "iedriver": "2.52.0"
 }
}
```

In the above object,replace the selenium version from `2.52` with `3.0.1` and save it. Now run `webdriver-manager update` in terminal. This will download the new version of selenium jar file that is mentioned in the config.json file.

Comment: I dont' have `config.json` in `/node_modules/protractor/config.json`.  I have try to update `config.json` in `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager` and no luck, webdriver-manager update still download selenium 2.53.1

Comment: Which version of protractor are you using?

Comment: I use protractor 4.0.10, default version from `node install protractor --save-dev` command `node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor --version`
`Version 4.0.10` and node `node -v
v6.9.1`